# MYSQL database storing error

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

> Error: INSERT INTO grocery ('GrocerID', 'GrocerName', 'Address',
>   'LogoImage') VALUES ('GID0072', 'BigBazaar','India, Andhra Pradesh,
>   522124','WIN_20150817_121614.JPG') You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''GrocerID', 'GrocerName', 'Address',
>   'LogoImage') VALUES ('GID0072', 'BigBazaar' at line 1

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "secret";
$dbname = "task";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$GrocerID=$_POST['GrocerID']; 
$GrocerName=$_POST['GrocerName'] ;
$Address=$_POST['Address'];
$LogoImage=$_POST['LogoImage'] ;




// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO grocery ('GrocerID', 'GrocerName', 'Address', 'LogoImage')
VALUES ('$GrocerID', '$GrocerName','$Address','$LogoImage')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header('Location:task.html');
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

[Data Base image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCboA.jpg)

Can someone please tell me what the mistake I'm doing here??

I have used
database name: task,
table name: grocery
But i'm not able to understand where I'm doing the mistake.

Thankyou

Comment: Remove `quotes` from `column name` instead use `backtick` !!

Comment: Thankyou satya I got it ;)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks

Comment: A backtick is this symbol " ` " it is the key on the left of the "1 and !" key

Answer (score 1):

not write coloumn in `''` use `backticks` ``

```
INSERT INTO grocery 
(GrocerID, GrocerName, Address, LogoImage) 
VALUES ('GID0072', 'BigBazaar','India, Andhra Pradesh, 522124','WIN_20150817_121614.JPG')
```

Answer (score 1):

Either Remove `'`

```
INSERT INTO grocery 
(GrocerID, GrocerName, Address, LogoImage) 
VALUES ('GID0072', 'BigBazaar','India, Andhra Pradesh, 522124','WIN_20150817_121614.JPG')
```

OR

Replace `'` with ` (backtick)

[**NOTE**: You can find `backtick` below `Esc key` in keyboard]

```
INSERT INTO grocery 
(`GrocerID`, `GrocerName`, `Address`, `LogoImage`) 
VALUES ('GID0072', 'BigBazaar','India, Andhra Pradesh, 522124','WIN_20150817_121614.JPG')
```

And, Use **real_escape_string()** to prevent `SQL Injection Attacks`

> PHP provides real_escape_string() to escape special characters in a
>   string before sending a query to MySQL. This function was adopted by
>   many to escape single quotes in strings and by the same occasion
>   prevent SQL injection attacks. However, it can create serious security
>   flaws when it is not used correctly.

```
$GrocerName = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['GrocerName']);
$Address = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Address']);
$LogoImage = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['LogoImage']);
```

Comment: Also provide some tips regarding sql injection to make your answer better!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO grocery (`GrocerID`, `GrocerName`, `Address`, `LogoImage`)
        VALUES ('$GrocerID', '$GrocerName','$Address','$LogoImage')";
```

Do not use **`quotes`** for `column_name`.